Keeping the correct coordinates when converting to a simple feature in R
This is the first part of a project I am working on where I am trying to determine if there is a correlation between car accidents and other variables.
To get started I read in the csv file containing the crash points and filtered it down to only include my target area. Then I geocoded the crash data and converted it to a simple feature so it can be mapped. When I go to plot the points, they are not on the correct coordinates even after ensuring I kept the right crs.
I know it is incorrect because it does not overlap with the other simple features (boundary of the city and primary roads) when plotted. I also checked the geometries of the crash data after I converted it to a simple feature, and it had the right coordinates but when mapped it is not where it is supposed to be.
geometry <- st_geometry(crashsf)
print(geometry)

Columbus boundary and roads

Vehicle crashes (crashsf)

All put together

library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggspatial)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(tmap)
library(mapview)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidycensus)
library(tigris)
library(units)
library(tidygeocoder) 

##Loading Crash data
crashData <- read.csv("D:/final Project - GEOG 5229/CrashStatistics.csv", 
        header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",
        dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")

#keeping Columbus only
#cbusCrashes <- crashData %>% 
  #filter(CityVillageTownshipName == "Columbus")
cbusCrashes <- crashData %>% mutate(CityVillageTownshipName = str_trim(CityVillageTownshipName)) %>% filter(CityVillageTownshipName == "Columbus")

cbusCrashes <- cbusCrashes %>% 
  filter(!is.na(LocationRoadName))

cbusCrashes$addressFull <- paste(cbusCrashes$LocationRoadName, cbusCrashes$LocationRoadType, 'Columbus, OH')

cbusCrashes$addressFull <- as.character(cbusCrashes$addressFull)

##Geocoding crash data
#geocoded <- cbusCrashes %>%
    #geocode(addressFull, method = 'arcgis', lat = Latitude, long = Longitude, full_results = TRUE)

names(geocoded)

##Removing NAs from geocoded data
geocoded <- geocoded %>% filter(complete.cases(.))

##Convert crash data to sf object and reproject to Ohio projection
crashsf <- geocoded %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Latitude...21, Longitude...22), as.numeric) %>% 
  st_as_sf(
    coords = c("Latitude...21", "Longitude...22"),
    agr = "constant",
    crs = 6350) 

geometry <- st_geometry(crashsf) 
print(geometry)

##Getting block group boundary for Franklin County
cbg_sf <- block_groups("OH", "Franklin", year = 2020) %>%
  st_transform(6350)

##Columbus boundary
subdivisions <- county_subdivisions(state = '39', county = '049')

columbus_boundary <- subdivisions[subdivisions$NAME == "Columbus", ]

columbus_boundary <- st_transform(columbus_boundary, crs = st_crs(cbg_sf))

##Loading in road inventory
roads <- st_read('D:/final Project - GEOG 5229/tl_2023_39_prisecroads')

roads <- st_transform(roads, crs = st_crs(cbg_sf))

roads <- st_as_sf(roads)

##Clip Franklin County block group and road inventory by boundary of Columbus
block_clipped <- st_intersection(cbg_sf, columbus_boundary)

roads_clipped <- st_intersection(roads, columbus_boundary)

#crashsf_clipped <- st_intersection(crashsf, columbus_boundary)

##Maps of data up to this point
#Census tracts and roads
ggplot()  + 
    geom_sf(data = block_clipped, fill = "lightgrey", color = "black", alpha = 0.5) + 
    geom_sf(data = roads_clipped, fill = "lightblue", color = "orange", alpha = 0.5)+ 
    labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") + 
  theme_minimal()

#Crash points 
ggplot()  + 
    geom_sf(data = crashsf, aes(geometry = geometry), color = "blue", size = 0.5) +
    labs( x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") + 
  theme_minimal()

ggplot()  + 
    geom_sf(data = block_clipped, fill = "lightgrey", color = "black", alpha = 0.5) + 
    geom_sf(data = roads_clipped, fill = "lightblue", color = "orange", alpha = 0.5)+ 
    geom_sf(data = crashsf, aes(geometry = geometry), color = "blue", size = 0.5) +
    labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") + 
  theme_minimal

dput (head(crashData))
Replying to @GrzegorzSapijaszko
structure(list(LocalReportNumber = c("\t22000056", "\t22000059",
"\t22000062", "\t2022-00000037", "\t2022-00000034", "\t22000013"
), DocumentNumber = c(20222017307, 20222017310, 20222017312,
20222017381, 20222017382, 20222018088), CrashSeverity = c("Property Damage Only",
"Property Damage Only", "Property Damage Only", "Property Damage Only",
"Property Damage Only", "Property Damage Only"), HitSkip = c("",
"", "", "", "", "Unsolved"), LocalInformation = c("", "", "",
"", "", ""), SecondaryCrash = c("False", "False", "False", "False",
"False", "False"), PhotosTaken = c("True", "False", "False",
"True", "True", "True"), OH2 = c("False", "False", "False", "False",
"False", "False"), OH3 = c("False", "False", "False", "False",
"False", "False"), OH1P = c("True", "False", "False", "False",
"False", "False"), OHOther = c("False", "False", "False", "False",
"False", "False"), PrivateProperty = c("False", "False", "False",
"False", "False", "False"), ReportingAgencyNCIC = c("\t02503",
"\t02503", "\t02503", "\t02507", "\t02507", "\t02505"), NumberOfUnits = c(1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), UnitInError = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
County = c("Franklin County", "Franklin County", "Franklin County",
"Franklin County", "Franklin County", "Franklin County"),
InCityVillageTownship = c("City", "City", "City", "City",
"City", "City"), CityVillageTownshipName = c("Dublin", "Dublin",
"Dublin", "Hilliard (RR name Hilliards)", "Hilliard (RR name Hilliards)",
"Grandview Heights"), CrashDateTime = c("1/6/2022 10:40:00 PM",
"1/7/2022 8:09:00 AM", "1/7/2022 9:10:00 PM", "1/6/2022 4:48:00 PM",
"1/6/2022 3:21:00 PM", "1/3/2022 3:00:00 PM"), FIPSPlaceCode = c(22694L,
22694L, 22694L, 35476L, 35476L, 31304L), Latitude = c(40.100521,
40.127097, NA, 40.020275, 40.032294, 39.984225), Longitude = c(-83.131351,
-83.150002, NA, -83.13799, -83.122533, -83.04499), LocationRouteType = c("Federal US Route",
"", "", "", "Interstate Route (Turnpike is also IR)", ""),
LocationRouteNumber = c("33", "", "", "", "270", ""), LocationPrefix = c("",
"", "", "", "", ""), LocationRoadName = c("", "MUIRFIELD",
"MUIRFIELD", "KRIGGSBY", "", "GRANDVIEW"), LocationRoadType = c("",
"Drive", "Drive", "Boulevard", "", "Avenue"), DistanceFromReference = c(NA,
50, 999, NA, NA, NA), DistanceReferenceMeasurement = c("",
"Feet", "Feet", "", "", ""), DirectionFromReference = c("",
"South", "South", "", "", ""), ReferenceRouteType = c("Interstate Route (Turnpike is also IR)",
"", "", "", "", ""), ReferenceRouteNumber = c("270", "",
"", "", "", ""), ReferencePrefix = c("", "", "", "", "East",
""), ReferenceName = c("", "BRAND", "CARNOUSTLE", "LEAP",
"CEMETERY", "1295"), ReferencePointUsed = c("Intersection",
"Intersection", "Intersection", "Intersection", "Intersection",
"House Number"), ReferenceRoadType = c("", "Road", "Drive",
"Road", "Road", ""), IntersectionOrApproachRelated = c("True",
"False", "False", "True", "False", "False"), NumberOfApproaches = c(4L,
NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA), WithinInterchangeArea = c("False", "True",
"True", "False", "False", "False"), LocationFirstHarmfulEvent = c("On Roadway",
"On Shoulder", "Outside Trafficway", "On Roadway", "On Roadway",
"On Roadway"), MannerOfCollision = c("Not Collision Between Two Vehicles in Transport",
"Not Collision Between Two Vehicles in Transport", "Not Collision Between Two Vehicles in Transport",
"Not Collision Between Two Vehicles in Transport", "Not Collision Between Two Vehicles in Transport",
"Not Collision Between Two Vehicles in Transport"), Weather = c("Snow",
"Clear", "Clear", "Snow", "Snow", "Clear"), LightCondition = c("Dark - Lighted Roadway",
"Daylight", "Dark - Lighted Roadway", "Daylight", "Daylight",
"Daylight"), ActiveSchoolZoneRelated = c("False", "False",
"False", "False", "False", "False"), WorkZoneRelated = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), WorkersPresent = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), LawEnforcementPresentInWorkZone = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), WorkZoneType = c("",
"", "", "", "", ""), WorkZoneLocation = c("", "", "", "",
"", ""), Narrative = c("INIT 1 WAS TRAVELING ON THE RAMP FROM US33 EAST TO IR 270 NORTH. UNIT 1 FAILED TO CONTROL HIS VEHICLE WHICH RESULTED IN THE VEHICKLE ROLLING IN THE ROADWAY AND COMING TO FINAL REST ON ITS TOP.",
"UNIT 1 WAS TRAVELING SOUTH ON MUIRFIELD DR. UNIT 1 DROVE OFF THE RIGHT SIDE OF THE ROAD STRIKING A CURB AND A LIGHT POLE.",
"UNIT 1 WAS TRAVELING NORTH ON MUIRFIELD DR APPROACHING CARNOUSTIE DR. THE DRIVER OF UNIT 1 STATED HE LOST CONTROL OF THE VEHICLE ON A PATCH OF ICE CROSSED THE DEPRESSED MEDIAN THEN CROSSED OVER THE SOUTHBOUND LANE OF TRAVEL AND ROLLED THE VEHICLE ONTO ITS SIDE AND CAME TO FINAL REST IN A TREELINE.",
"SAID VEHICLE WAS TRAVELING SOUTH ON LEAP RD. AS THE DRIVER WAS TURNING EAST ONTO KRIGGSBY BLVD THE DRIVER LOST CONTROL AND HIT A CITY ST SIGN.",
"VEHICLE WAS TRAVELING NORTH ON IR 270. UNIT 1 LOST CONTROL OF THE VEHICLE AND SWERVED TOWARDS THE EXIT RAMP OF THE CEMETERY RD EAST EXIT.  THE VEHICLE HIT THE EXIT SIGN AND DISPLACED THE SIGN. THE WILL NEED TO BE REPLACED.",
"UNIT 2 WAS PARKED FROM NORTH TO SOUTH IN FRONT OF 1295 GRANDVIEW AVE.  UNIT 1 TRAVELED SOUTHBOUND ON GRANDVIEW AVE; STRUCK UNIT 2 ON THE DRIVERS SIDE; THEN LEFT THE SCENE WITHOUT PLACING ANY INFORMATION ON THE VEHICLE."
), ReportTakenBy = c("Police", "Police", "Police", "Police",
"Police", "Motorist"), Supplement = c("False", "False", "False",
"False", "False", "False"), CrashReportedDateTime = c("1/6/2022 10:40:00 PM",
"1/7/2022 8:09:00 AM", "1/7/2022 9:10:00 PM", "1/6/2022 4:48:00 PM",
"1/6/2022 3:21:00 PM", "1/5/2022 11:58:00 AM"), DispatchedDateTime = c("1/6/2022 10:42:00 PM",
"1/7/2022 8:11:00 AM", "1/7/2022 9:11:00 PM", "1/6/2022 4:53:00 PM",
"1/6/2022 3:22:00 PM", "1/5/2022 12:00:00 AM"), ArrivedDateTime = c("1/6/2022 10:48:00 PM",
"1/7/2022 8:18:00 AM", "1/7/2022 9:17:00 PM", "1/6/2022 4:57:00 PM",
"1/6/2022 3:35:00 PM", "1/5/2022 12:19:00 PM"), SceneClearedDateTime = c("",
"1/7/2022 8:54:00 AM", "1/7/2022 10:50:00 PM", "1/6/2022 5:13:00 PM",
"1/6/2022 3:54:00 PM", "1/5/2022 12:20:00 PM"), OtherInvestigationTime = c(90L,
20L, 0L, 30L, 60L, 60L), TotalTimeRoadwayClosed = c(182L,
45L, 0L, 50L, 92L, 0L), OfficerName = c("SINCLAIR", "MANN",
"HOWARD", "JACKSON", "JACKSON", "HILES; S"), OfficerBadgeNumber = c("4734",
"3297", "1009", "685", "685", "327"), CheckedByOfficerName = c("KOVAS",
"CLARK", "HOWARD", "REED", "REED", "CHICKEY; J"), CheckedByBadgeNumber = c("4647",
"365", "1009", "6S67", "6S67", "329"), RoadwayDivided = c("False",
"True", "True", "False", "False", "False"), DividedLaneTravelDirection = c("",
"South", "North", "", "", ""), DividedMedianType = c("",
"Divided; Raised Median (Any type)", "Divided; Depressed Median",
"", "", ""), RoadContour = c("Curve Grade", "Curve Level",
"Curve Grade", "Straight Level", "Straight Level", "Straight Level"
), RoadCondition = c("Snow", "Dry", "Other/Unknown", "Snow",
"Snow", "Dry"), RoadSurface = c("Blacktop; Bituminous; Asphalt",
"Blacktop; Bituminous; Asphalt", "Blacktop; Bituminous; Asphalt",
"Blacktop; Bituminous; Asphalt", "Blacktop; Bituminous; Asphalt",
"Blacktop; Bituminous; Asphalt"), TotalInjured = c(0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), TotalKilled = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
TotalMinutes = c(0L, 63L, 99L, 50L, 92L, 800L), AnimalRelated = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), AnimalDeerRelated = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), AlcoholRelated = c("True",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), DrugRelated = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), BicycleRelated = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), MotorCycleRelated = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), SpeedRelated = c("False",
"True", "True", "False", "False", "False"), PedestrianRelated = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), SemiTruckRelated = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), SmallTruckRelated = c("True",
"False", "False", "True", "True", "False"), YouthRelated = c("True",
"True", "True", "True", "False", "False"), TeenRelated = c("False",
"False", "True", "True", "False", "False"), DUI21Related = c("True",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), SeniorRelated = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), FatalNotReportable = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), CommercialRelated = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), CommercialAtFault = c("False",
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False")), row.names = c(NA,
6L), class = "data.frame")

We don't have your data files and you don't show us any summary information about the objects you are creating so its very hard to follow through your code. How far out are things? Can you show one or two examples?

I do suspect your crashData from .csv file is in EPSG:4326 instead of EPSG:6350. So, I would suspect crashsf <- geocoded %>%  [...]  crs = 6350) is causing the issue. Try [...] crs = "EPSG:4328") |> sf::st_transform(crs = "EPSG:6350").

Would you share a dput(head(crashData)) in readable (text) please? Seems your source data is in 'EPSG:4326' (Longitude and Latitude deegres), not "EPSG:6350" x, y meters.

It would also be prudent to look at the results of creating an sf object before you geocode the data as the issue could be coming from those functions. However, as already pointed out EPSG:6350 is NAD83(2011) / Conus Albers and your coordinates appear to be lat/long so, EPSG:4326 would be the correct definition.

@user280502 You appear to have duplicate logins. See the Help Center about reconciling your logins, so you can edit your own post.

As said, your original csv data is in Latitude, Longitude (geographic degrees) format, not in EPSG:6350 (NAD83(2011) / Conus Albers) projected system. When you create your sf object you should specify 4326 and then convert it to 6350 like:
crash_data <- crashData |>
  subset(!is.na(Longitude) | !is.na(Latitude), select = c(LocalReportNumber, Longitude, Latitude)) |>
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = "EPSG:4326") |>
  sf::st_transform(crs = "EPSG:6350")

cbg_sf <- tigris::block_groups("OH", "Franklin", year = 2020) |>
  sf::st_transform(crs = "EPSG:6350")

tmap::qtm(cbg_sf, fill = "white") +
  tmap::qtm(crash_data) +
  tmap::tm_graticules() +
  tmap::tmap_style("cobalt")


Created on 2024-12-05 with reprex v2.1.1.9000
In your above code it would be around:
crashsf <- geocoded %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Latitude...21, Longitude...22), as.numeric) %>% 
  st_as_sf(
    coords = c("Latitude...21", "Longitude...22"),
    agr = "constant",
    crs = 4326)  |>
  st_transform(crs = "EPSG:6350")

That should solve the issue.
